# how to send message to my device from my server to android device using GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, message

I am using Google cloud Messaging for sending messages from my server to android devices...I have used the example from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

But I am unable to send message to the device.

Please help me for this.
I will thank full to you.

Comment: Please write more about what is your problem.

Comment: Thanks SaurabhJinturkar, i have solved this question. But I have one more question to you is that I want to create a background service in android to update the location time to time of device to my web server. So, please give me the simple example to do this. Thanks in advance.